# Please clarify whether I need a Bing api key for this app

Tags: bing-maps

In my application I need to use Bing maps as a base map.
http://svn.openlayers.org/branches/openlayers/2.11/examples/bing.html(open in IE)

I followed this example.
For this there is no bing key is added in that example.
Only they included below .ashx file...
Can I include this .ashx (http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2&mkt=en-us) file ?
In that .ashx file ther is credentils="some key is there" , so thats y i got the doubt.. Can I use it legally?
Please clarify my doubt ??

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need your own Key.

You can get it from the official Bing Maps API site: http://bingmapsportal.com/

Once you have your own key, you can use it like it is used in this sample:

http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/bing.html